# how to avoid change string to number automaticlly in r

Tags: r, matrix, numeric

I was trying to save some string into a matrix, but it automatically changed to numbers (levels). How can i avoid it??

Here is the table:

```
  trt    means  M
1 0   12.16673  a
2 111 11.86369 ab
3 125 11.74433 ab
4 14  11.54073  b

I wanna to save to a matrix like:
J0001 a ab ab b

But, what i get is: 
J0001 1 2 2 3
```

How can i avoid this?

Comment: I suspect M is a `factor`, so maybe you need to use `as.character`...

Comment: Also, consider using a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix` if you are using `numeric`s with a `factor` and want to retain the appearance of a `character`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `M` column is defined as a `factor`.  You can save it as-is by wrapping it with  `as.character`

```
> dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "trt    means  M
  1 0   12.16673  a
  2 111 11.86369 ab
  3 125 11.74433 ab
  4 14  11.54073  b")
> as.numeric(dat$M)
# [1] 1 2 2 3
> as.character(dat$M)
# [1] "a"  "ab" "ab" "b"
```

You can avoid this in the first place by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you read the data into R, or take advantage of the `colClasses` argument in some of the read-in functions.